# How to split up the elements in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a  matrix A

```
 1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1
 1     1     0     0
 1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
```

if d=[1 2 3],

```
for i=2:length(d)
  d(i) = d(i) + d(i-1); %d=[1 3 6]
end
```

then using,

```
d = [0, ceil((d./d(end))*length(x))]; %d=[2 5 9]
disp('The resultant split up is:')
for i=2:length(d)
  disp(x((d(i-1)+1):d(i)));
end
```

the output has to be,
The split up is:
1st split up->

```
          1     1     0     0    %first 2 rows in matrix A
          0     1     0     0
```

2nd split up->

```
          1     0     0     1    %next 3 rows
          0     0     1     0
          0     0     0     0
```

3rd split up->

```
          0     1     1     1    %next 4 rows
          1     1     0     0
          1     0     0     0
          0     0     0     1
```

Comment: I apologize for the blunt comment, but this is way too verbose. What is the question?

Comment: say if my encoded bits are 10001100, if the user enter the hop count matrix to [3 2 3] the output should 100    01   100 .the bits are split using the above mentioned logic.

Comment: @EitanT: the prob here is that my encoded bit stream is in a mXn matrix format. i need to split the elements in the matrix according to the hop count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) is what you need: Here's a short example:

```
%// Bits and hops array
bits = '10001100';
hops = [3 2 3];

A = mat2cell(bits(:)', 1, hops)
```

The result is a cell array of strings:

```
A = 
    '100'    '01'    '100'
```

This approach works with number arrays as well (*e.g* `bits = [1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]`).

Comment: 'Error: Illegal use of reserved keyword "end".  ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.    Error in ==> @(x,y)bits(x:y)   Error in ==> arraysplit at 10   A = arrayfun(@(x, y)bits(x:y), startidx, endidx, 'Uniform', 0). It showed this error when i executed this prog.

Comment: for any given input number arrays, depending on the hop count it should be split. [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0] and the hopcount is [3 2 3], the output should print the first 6 numbers then the next 4 and then the next 5 numbers.

Comment: @AnnieSharon Did you mean that `hopcount = [6 4 5]`? Anyway, my answer does exactly what you want, but it can be applied on 1-D vectors only. If you want a matrix solution, please specify how your data matrix and `hopcount` look like.

Comment: but the output of my prog is a matrix. i need to split the elements in this matrix according to the hop count. its not like if my hop is 3 , three bits are to be displayed. the bits in the raio 3:2:3 should be displayed

Comment: i have edited my question..! the hop count is user defined..! it is enter dynamically by the user. the matrix[3 2 3] is correctly oly. the bits in the  encoded matrix should be displayed in the ratio of the hop count

Comment: What do you mean "ratio of hopcount"? If you introduce new terminology, please bother to explain it. How does the wall-of-text in your question bear any relevance to your question? Can't you give an understandable example with an input matrix, a hop count matrix (or whatever it is) and the desired result **in the body of the question** to illustrate what you want? Your problem sounds simple enough, but you really make it a hard time to understand your question and answer it properly.

Comment: i have edited the question. this code works if i give a number array. but how to do it for a matrix?

Comment: @AnnieSharon instead of cluttering your question with loads of code, can you explain in simple words what you want to do? And what is "ratio of hopcount"? Possibly provide a _short_ example of input and desired output please.

Comment: @AnnieSharon Can you give an example of splitting a matrix?

Comment: I have appended the desired output..!